# Info on type family instances

Tags: haskell, ghci, type-families

**Intro:**

While checking out [snoyman's "persistent"](http://github.com/snoyberg/persistent) library I found myself wanting ghci's (or another tool) assistance in figuring out stuff.

ghci's `:info` doesn't seem to work as nicely with type-families and data-families as it does with "plain" types:

```
> :info Maybe
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a     -- Defined in Data.Maybe
...
> :info Persist.Key Potato -- "Key Potato" defined in example below
data family Persist.Key val     -- Defined in Database.Persist
... (no info on the structure/identity of the actual instance)
```

One can always look for the instance in the source code, but sometimes it could be hard to find it and it may be hidden in template-haskell generated code etc.

Code example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies, QuasiQuotes #-}

import qualified Database.Persist as Persist
import Database.Persist.Sqlite as PSqlite

PSqlite.persistSqlite [$persist|
Potato
    name String
    isTasty Bool
    luckyNumber Int
    UniqueId name
|]
```

What's going on in the code example above is that Template-Haskell is generating code for us here. All the extensions above except for `QuasiQuotes` are required because the generated code uses them.

I found out what `Persist.Key Potato` is by doing:

```
-- test.hs:
test = PSqlite.persistSqlite [$persist|
...
-- ghci:
> :l test.hs 
> import Language.Haskell.TH
> import Data.List
> runQ test >>= putStrLn . unlines . filter (isInfixOf "Key Potato") . lines . pprint
    where newtype Database.Persist.Key Potato = PotatoId Int64
type PotatoId = Database.Persist.Key Potato
```

**Question:**

Is there an easier way to get information on instances of type families and data families, using ghci or any other tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does `-ddump-splices` show you the TH-generated code in this case?

Otherwise, `:browse` does give you info about data family instances, though not about type families.

You might want to file a [ghc ticket](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/) - the `:browse` output looks mangled, and one might expect data family instances to be reported like class instances, by `:info`.

Comment: @claus: 10x. `:browse` is awesome! `-ddump-splices` does show the TH-generated code. Also turns out that it shows it nicer than `pprint` does (`"boo"` vs `['b',\n'o',\n'o'\n]` etc), thought `runQ/pprint`'s output is not just dumped so I could filter it etc